# SVG border appears trimmed

Tags: svg

I think I am missing an apparent offset issue in my very first svg here, The top and left borders are tirmmed (pointed by red arrow), Also if something like nested `<g>` or `<symbol>` is possible pleas let me know, Thanks. (screenshot in FF27)
.

[image]

The simplified code and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpss/vGNMu/)

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <symbol id="ringCenters" style="fill:black;">
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="2" />
            /*...more circles*/
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="ring1" class="rings">
            <path d="M99.9746,51.5943 
                     A50 50 0 1 0 
                     62.5254,98.4057" 
                     stroke="green" />
            <path d="M99.9746,51.5943 
                     A50 50 0 0 1 
                     62.5254,98.4057" 
                     stroke="red" />
        </symbol>
        /*...more rings*/
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#ringCenters" x="10" y="10" />
    /*...more rings*/
</svg>
```

```
.rings{fill:none;}

svg {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stroke around a shape is always *centered* on the exact geometric border of the shape, and so extends beyond the shape by half the stroke width.

If for any reason you don't want to use `overflow:visible`, another option is therefore to just adjust the positions of your shape so that you have a bit of padding on the edges, equal to half the stroke width.  (Of course, that assumes that the stroke-width will be the same every time you use the symbol.)

Note that you have to adjust the position of the `<path>` within the `<symbol>`, not just the position of the `<symbol>` within your SVG.  That's because each reference to a symbol element [is drawn as if it was a nested `<svg>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement) within it's own viewport, with a fixed height, width, and "viewBox" coordinate system.  You're not setting those attributes on the symbol, so they end up as the defaults for nested SVGs: width and height equal to 100% of the parent, and a default coordinate system with (0,0) at the top left corner of the viewport.

That "nested SVG" then gets positioned so that it's top left corner is at the (x,y) position specified in the `<use>` element, but as far as the drawing content within the symbol is concerned, the rectangular edges of that viewport are the edges of the drawing surface.  Unless, of course, you specifically allow overflow, as @helderdarocha suggested.

(By the way, the symbols-are-drawn-as-nested-SVGs idea is probably why you needed to specify `svg{ overflow:visible;}` for Firefox, although it really should work by setting the property on the symbols directly; I'd call that a Firefox bug.)

**On your other question:** `<g>` elements can be nested multiple times without problem.  For `<symbol>` elements, it's not so clear.  [The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SymbolElement) say that symbols are much like `<g>` elements except (a) they have viewports and (b) the symbol is not drawn directly, it is only available for reference by a `<use>` element.

Now, that suggests that `<symbol>`s can be nested like `<g>` elements.  And on Chrome it works.  On Firefox, not so much.  I assume what is happening is that when Firefox copies the internal content of the outer `<symbol>`, it treats the internal `<symbol>` elements as if they were just symbol *definitions*, not as if they were *renderings* of those symbols.

I.e. code like this

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol id="complicated">
       <symbol id="firstPart">
            <path d="...."/>
       </symbol>
       <symbol id="secondPart">
            <path d="...."/>
       </symbol>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#complicated"/>
</svg>
```

Gets rendered as if it was

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol id="complicated">
       <symbol id="firstPart">
            <path d="...."/>
       </symbol>
       <symbol id="secondPart">
            <path d="...."/>
       </symbol>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <g> <!-- The <use> element is drawn as if it was a <g> element -->
     <svg> <!-- The <symbol> element is drawn as if it was a nested <svg> -->
       <symbol id="firstPart"> <!-- the internal symbol is copied as-is -->
            <path d="...."/>
       </symbol>
       <symbol id="secondPart"> <!-- but symbols aren't drawn directly! -->
            <path d="...."/>
       </symbol>
    <svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

...and that shouldn't really be rendered as anything at all.  This, I wouldn't call a Firefox "bug", just a literal interpretation of the specs, which don't give any special treatment to nested symbol elements.

There is a way to get symbols to nest, however, and that's to use `<use>` elements within the symbol definition:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol id="firstPart">
        <path d="...."/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="secondPart">
        <path d="...."/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="complicated">
        <use xlink:href="#firstPart"/>
        <use xlink:href="#secondPart"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#complicated"/>
</svg>
```

Here's your fiddle updated with that structure: http://jsfiddle.net/vGNMu/6/

Comment: "_another option is therefore to just adjust the positions of your shape so that you have a bit of padding on the edges_", i.e. why I added `x="10" y="10"` to the `use` tags, is that not right?  And both `overflow:visible` and _nested_ `symbol` tags work in chrome but not in firefox :(

Comment: When I nest `symbol` or `g` tags nothing appears in FF27!

Comment: Nesting `<g>` elements should always work -- show me an example where it doesn't!  Nesting symbol elements I wasn't sure of (the specs aren't clear), which is why I created the fiddle -- but I clearly should have tested it cross-browser!  I'll update to correct that -- and to add some clarification about why your padding attempt wasn't working.

Comment: ooh so that's how the `<use>` gets rendered, with its own _non-exposed_ `<svg>`, `<g>` and viewport with default coordinate system, Thank you loads!!!

Comment: Yeah, it takes a while to get your head around it.  I've been playing around with [using `<symbol>` for icons, where the icon itself uses an `<image>` to position a PNG sprite sheet](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/ftIEj), and discovered that things can get messy with the layered viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes.  Somehow `overflow:hidden` is getting lost in the mix...

Comment: Thanks, With that amazing [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/ftIEj) of yours I was able to practice on `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` more - http://jsfiddle.net/rpss/ugT35/, Hopefully I got it right ^_^

Comment: Hmmm now only tested it in chrome, not working great, only in FF, guess for SVG better test it cross-browser all the time :/

Comment: Are you talking about the browser differences in default SVG sizes?  That is definitely a pain...  When creating a separate SVG for definitions, also be careful not to use `display:none;` The display property is not *supposed* to affect your ability to use any `<def>`-type content in other SVGs, but it doesn't work that way in Firefox, so I always have to use something like `svg.defsOnly{height:0; width:0; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}`

Answer (score 3):

Half of your stroke is outside the viewBox. You can avoid clipping by using:

```
svg, symbol {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Or adding an `overflow="visible"` attribute to each symbol.

Your [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vGNMu/5/)

Comment: when I add `overflow: visible;` to `symbol`, it works in _chrome(33)_ but not in _firefox(27)_ and when I add `overflow: visible;` to `svg` it works in FF but not in chrome!

Comment: so... I added it to both!